# Getting RangeError when calling decodeTransferCheckedInstructionUnchecked

Tags: transactions, spl-token, decode

Getting the following error

```
RangeError: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 8. Received 9
```

When I try to call `decodeTransferCheckedInstructionUnchecked` on the 3rd tx instruction of this tx: https://solscan.io/tx/5Aybc2PhNy9KJepxTML95K137FvMhZWhbpdcxgtuqE5yj2X6Q7QpSQ5Fg2ttkinB7NHn1s8wqNMRLcQkWwhmnmJw

`decodeTransferCheckedInstructionUnchecked` is from the  `"@solana/spl-token"` package
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#decodeTransferCheckedInstructionUnchecked
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, that instruction is a `transfer` instruction, and not a `transferChecked` instruction. Instead of using `decodeTransferCheckedInstructionUnchecked`, use `decodeTransferInstruction` or `decodeTransferInstructionUnchecked`.